# Why should return-by-value be const for non-builtin types but not const for builtin types?

Tags: c++, templates, return-by-value

Solutions 4 and 5 on **[GotW #6 Const-Correctness](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/006.htm)** mention this:

> ```
> Point GetPoint( const int i ) {
>     return points_[i];
> }
> ```
>
> Return-by-value should normally be const for non-builtin return types ..
>
> ---
>
> ```
> int GetNumPoints() {
>     return points_.size();
> }
> ```
>
> .. **since the int is already an rvalue and to put in 'const' can interfere with template instantiation and is confusing, misleading, and probably fattening**.

I have the following questions

1. Which template instantiation are we interfering with here ?!
2. What exactly is misleading here and why?
3. Why this differentiation between non-builtins and builtins. I thought this was a bad practice!

Comment: Note that it's no longer good practice to put `const` on any return values, because you effectively disable move semantics. So at least you don't have to worry too much. :)

Comment: @GManNickG: But I still really want to understand this. Also, could you please expand your comment (probably into an answer) as to why const will disable move semantics?

Comment: @Lazer A move constructor can usually be implemented as a swap, but only if the constructor argument is non-const -- if it's const, you won't be able to swap, because it's read-only.

Comment: @hvd: Swapping doesn't really have anything to do with it. Moving simply requires that you modify the parameter (so that it no longer owns the resource), which you can't do when it's `const`. Whether or not that's done with swap is irrelevent.

Comment: @GManNickG C++ allows for `static_cast<const T &&>(t)`, does it not? It could then be passed to a `T(const T &&)` constructor for an uncommon move-like constructor. Moving doesn't *require* modifying the parameter, moving allows it.

Comment: @hvd: Yes, such a constructor is fine, but useless. The standard even remarks on its uselessness (§12.8/4). Moving in the sense of the verb *does* require the source be modified, otherwise no moving has been done, only copying. Sure, you can use the types to differentiate constructors for whatever reason you'd like, but then they're no longer move-constructors, but constructors that happen to take r-value references for some arbitrary reason. Don't mix up "move semantics" with "r-value references".

Comment: @GManNickG The standard disagrees: "A non-template constructor for class X is a move constructor if its first parameter is of type X&&, const X&&, volatile X&&, or const volatile X&&, and either there are no other parameters or else all other parameters have default arguments"

Comment: @hvd: Fair enough, though I'll argue that's merely a categorization based on argument types, not functionality. When *we* say move, though, we talk about functionality, not category. (Obviously neither is intrinsically default, but as programmers functionality of constructors is more interesting than their categorical name.)

Comment: @GManNickG Agreed, and I believe my initial comment here also agrees with that.

Answer (score 4):

```
Return-by-value should normally be const for non-builtin return types ..
```

That is not correct- one of the relatively few mistakes in the GotW. `const` rvalues were questionable in C++03 and definitely very bad in C++11.

The problem is that in C++03, rvalues can have any member function called on them- even non-const. This is great because you can "swaptimize" or perform method chains and other things, which are perfectly fine and make absolute sense, but it's also bad because the compiler can't catch you when you do something stupid, like assign to it or something. Generally, it's a bad idea to restrict everyone from doing good things because the caller *might* do something stupid. The intention is good, but it's not right.

In C++11 this is fixed because you can disallow member functions from being called on rvalues, and secondly, because in order for move semantics to work correctly the rvalue must be mutable. You can't take resources from an rvalue if it's `const`.

Just as a note, the reason this is different is because primitive types have always had special wording built into the language which made e.g. assigning to rvalues illegal, so there was no need to try and enforce that yourself by making it `const`.

As for the template instantiations, I'm actually uncertain. This practice was already known to be bad by the time I started coding C++, so it's not something I ever had to deal with.

Comment: How do you disallow member functions from being called on rvalues?

Comment: "The problem is that in C++03, rvalues can have any member function called on them- even non-const." -- Maybe I'm just not understanding you, but that's a reason _for_ `const`-qualified rvalues, is it not? You cannot call non-`const` member functions on `const` rvalues.

Comment: @MikeSeymour It's new syntax in C++11, I forgot the precise syntax, but it's something like to `void f() & {}` and `void f() && {}` to even overload on rvalueness.

Comment: @MikeSeymour But apparently I'm a good guesser: that is the right syntax (at least as it was proposed, in http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2439.htm)

Comment: @hvd: It is an argument in favour of `const` rvalues. However, as I explain, it does more harm than good, even in C++03, even ignoring the problems you've introduced to C++11 for no benefit.

Comment: @DeadMG Thanks, it was not clear to me that you intended it to be read in that way because of the start of the sentence "The problem is...", but now that you explained, it makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I disagree with the recommendation to put `const` on the return value independent of move semantics: the value is already an rvalue and as a result there isn't much danger of accidentally modifying it. This is the part of why to put a `const` on non-built-in types: they may contain some sort of a backdoor to the value. For example, `std::vector<T>` has a `swap()` method which can be used to "steal" the content of a non-const rvalue:

```
std::vector<int> f();
std::vector<int> value;
f().swap(value);
```

Similarly, streams have some member operators which allow you to use them with certain built-in functions which effectively extract a reference from the stream, e.g.:

```
std::string word;
std::istringstream("hello, world") >> std::skipws >> word;
```

Without the `std::skipws` the stream is an rvalue which can't be bound to the first argument of `std::operator>> (std::istream&, std::string&)` but using the member operator for manipulators returns a non-const reference to the stream.

The `const` on build-in types actually has no effect at all. In particular, when passing the result of a function on to a function template (in C++2003) it can't distinguish between a `const` or a non-`const` return being passed on. As a result, it may appear as if the `const` has an effect on built-in returns although it actually doesn't.

As I said, I disagree with the rule and in C++2011 it definitely doesn't hold because you **want** to be able to move off a non-built-in anyway which would be prevented by the `const` return.